# Banner background image screen resolution

Tags: html, css, resolution, screen-resolution

I am in the process of creating a website which I have at the temp link: http://ryanterpilowski.co.uk/urofoam/

As you can see for the main banner, I have used a background-image, with text fading in. I am happy with how it looks on normal desktop screens... but when viewed on a widescreen (1600x1200) upwards .. the background image gets cropped up You can see example here: http://www.infobyip.com/testwebsiteresolution.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fryanterpilowski.co.uk%2Furofoam%2F&width=1680&height=1050&in_browser=true.

I can't see where I would control this in my css, can anyone help?

Comment: dont provide link...just make jsfiddle

Comment: On very quick, possibly simple solution is to set `background-position: 50%;` on the elements. Just means that they will be centred when they stretch beyond the bounds of the container.

Comment: Thank you @JamieBarker ... it is more of a problem when viewd at resolutions of 2560x1440 and 1920x1200..  you can hardly see the image... it is almost like it is zooming it

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Responsive Web Development(RWD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211090/how-to-auto-adjust-the-div-size-for-all-mobile-tablet-display-formats/25380422#25380422). To make page responsive to all device we need to use some basic fundamental of RWD.

You can use the CSS3 [**Media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)  where you can target different screen sizes.

**For Example:**

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {

/* Styles inside this only work when your device width is between 320px to 480px. Same you can set for other sizes*/


}
```

For more details please have look in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25211090/how-to-auto-adjust-the-div-size-for-all-mobile-tablet-display-formats/25380422#25380422)

To just make image responsive just try:

```
img{ max-width: 100%;}
```

OR

```
.your-class-name { 
  background: url(images/yourimage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Please check this [Large Background Images and Screen Sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471576/large-background-images-and-screen-sizes)

Comment: Thanks Mike. As you can see from the link my website works great on a mobile, i pad etc... I have media queiries for all of these... the problem I am having is when I am going larger.. like when someone is viewing my website on a widescreen tv for example.

Comment: The image looks fine, it is the fact of it being cropped... you can see here: http://www.infobyip.com/testwebsiteresolution.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fryanterpilowski.co.uk%2Furofoam%2F&width=2560&height=1440&in_browser=true

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@media rule` of CSS, where you can adress different screen sizes (and much more). 
Take a look at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

In your case, you can use `min-width` and `min-height` to define different beheaviour on such devices:

```
@media (min-height: 1200px) and (min-width: 1600px) {
    /* Your CSS here for this special case */
    header {
       /* .. */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that... Where abouts would I add that media query?

Comment: If you try resizing the website he supplied as link, and actually inspect the CSS code of the website, you'd see that he's already using media queries.

Comment: You just put it in your default css-file @RyanTerps